# How do I loop through all sheets and rename based on the active sheet cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that will look through all sheets in the workbook, and if a sheet name contains "blank", to rename that sheet with the value in cell C1.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Rename()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetBlank As Worksheet
Set sheetBlank = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim nameCell As Range
Set nameCell = ActiveSheet.Range("C1")
    
For Each ws In Sheets
    If sheetBlank.Name Like "*blank*" Then
    sheetBlank.Name = nameCell.Value
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Now, this *does* rename the first active sheet, but it is not making any changes to the rest of them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I prefer `If InStr(ws.Name, "blank") Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referring to the wrong worksheet:

```vb
Sub Rename()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "*blank*" Then
            ws.Name = ws.Range("C1").Value
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You set your objects outside the loop and never touch them again.
If you're going to use "ActiveSheet" you need to `.Activate` each sheet in order to work, but that's not a good approach since your iterator (ws) represents the sheet object.

```
Public Sub Rename()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        If InStr(1, Ws.Name, "blank", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then _
            Ws.Name = Ws.Range("C1").Value2
    Next Ws
End Sub
```